# Discrete Random Variable measure theoretic

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading a book on measure foundations for probability theory.

On a page, after defining r.v. as measurable functions, speaking of the probability distribution associated with the r.v., the authors define a r.v. like this:

$X(\omega)=a$, with probability p.

$X(\omega)=b$, with probability (1-p).

This doesn't seem like a proper definition, since 'with prob. p' could be translated into '$P(X^{-1}(B))=p$, when $a\in B$ '. So, we're defining $X$ with itself, but not in a consistent way I think...

Is there a way to define it without itself?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $B'$? You can say nothing about its measure unless you define it.

Comment: @iiivooo $B \in \mathbf{B}(\mathbb{R})$, and by the way, I like your user name. ;)

Comment: In that case $P(X^{-1}(B))=1-p$ if $b \in B$ and zero otherwise. Please see my answer for details.

Comment: could you add a source for this?

Comment: @user190080 http://www.amazon.co.uk/Integral-Probability-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1852337818/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1445442191&sr=1-1&keywords=measure+integral+and+probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X(\omega)=a$ with probability $p$ means, that $X(\omega)=a$ for all $\omega \in \Omega_a$, such that $P(\Omega_a)=p$. Similarly you define $X(\omega)=b$ for all $\omega \in \Omega_b$, such that $P(\Omega_b)=1-p$. Now we can see, that we defined r.v. $X$ on set of measure 1 (the intersection of $\Omega_a$ and $\Omega_b$ is clearly empty if $a \neq b$). Therefore it is proper definition of r.v.

**Edit:**
To defined $\Omega_a$ and $\Omega_b$ first you have to define $\Omega$ and $P$. Since you did not do it, I define the space $\Omega$ having just two elements  $\Omega=\{\omega_a,\omega_b\}$ and $P(\omega_a)=p$ and $P(\omega_b)=1-p$ and then I define $X(\omega_a)=a$ and $X(\omega_b)=b$. 
But you must accept, that this concept with space $\Omega$ is abstract, and in dealing with r.v. you do not need to know (in fact you do not care) about what $\Omega_a$ is exactly, you just need to know its measure.

Also to your example:
$$P(X^{-1}(B))=P(\{\omega \in \Omega :X(\omega) \in B\}$$
so we immediately see, that for borel $B$ we have 4 cases:

$P(X^{-1}(B))=1$ if both $a,b \in B$,

$P(X^{-1}(B))=p$ if $a \in B$ and $b \notin B$,

$P(X^{-1}(B))=1-p$ if $a \notin B$ and $b \in B$,

$P(X^{-1}(B))=0$ if both $a,b \notin B$.

Comment: $P: \Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$, but $B \subset $ range of $X$, not the domain...

Comment: Sorry my notation could confuse you so I changed it, hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm learning this, so I still have some doubts on your answer: 1) if $p=1-p$ the sets$\Omega_a, \Omega_b$ could intersect, right? Also, by $\Omega_a, \Omega_b$ do you mean any set that $P(\Omega_a)=p$ and $P(\Omega_b)=1-p$, or the whole collection of subsets where the equalities are true? Because from how you write it seems as if you're saying that $\Omega_a \cup \Omega_b=\Omega$

Comment: No, $\Omega_a$ and $\Omega_b$ are two fixed sets (fixed in definition of r.v.). However for dealing with r.v. the only desired information you need about them is their measure. Also if $\omega$ is in both, than you have $a=X(\omega)=b$, which is contradiction with $a \neq b$ therefore their intersection is empty. Also $P(\Omega_a \cup \Omega_b)=1$, so $X$ is defined on set of measure 1. There could be some elements outside both sets, but you can define $X$ on them as you want, since their measure is zero.

Comment: ok. I think I'm getting there. =)  so they are fixed sets, but when $p=1-p$ they are not defined in a unique way only by their measure... So, how would you define those omega sets in this case?

Comment: I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30552/discussion-between-an-old-man-in-the-sea-and-iiivooo).